# Replace the username/password authentication to Salesforce with Oauth

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, salesforce

As the title I'm working on a web server that allow you user access data by validate username and password then send back a session. Now, I want to change it by using Oauth from Salesforce but I'm new in API.

I have google it but still not understand that yet. Can someone explain to me how to change it and that will be the best with example or tutorial in java.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What language / framework are you building your app with?

Comment: I'm working on java Sir.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help but I've created some Typesafe Activator templates that will help you setup new projects using Salesforce OAuth, Play Framework, and Java: http://typesafe.com/activator/template/reactive-salesforce-rest-javascript-seed http://typesafe.com/activator/template/reactive-salesforce-rest-angular-crud http://typesafe.com/activator/template/salesforce-canvas-seed